# understanding statement of generalized CLT

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

[Durrett Theorem 3.7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuRIr.png)

Given a sum $S_n=\sum_1^nX_i$ of an iid sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ Durrett theorem 3.7.2 (image at link) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of constants $a_n,b_n$ such that $(S_n-b_n)/a_n$ converges weakly to a nondegenerate distribution. I am trying to see how the usual CLT, ie, when $var(X_1)<\infty$, relates to this theorem.

Let the $X_i$ have the double exponential distribution, with pdf $f(x)=\exp(-|x|)/2$. The variance is 2 and the density is symmetric so the usual CLT says $S_n/\sqrt{2n}$ converges to a standard normal.

Now to Durrett's theorem. Again since the pdf is symmetric condition $(i)$ is met with $\theta=1/2$ and also $b_n=0$. $P(|X_1|>x)=e^{-x}$ so $a_n=\inf\{x:P(|X_1|>x)\le 1/n)\}=\log n.$ So the theorem seems to be saying $S_n/\log n$ converges to a nondegenerate distribution, which cannot be, given the CLT result. So I must have miscalculated $a_n$ or I'm misunderstanding the statement of the theorem.

I also do not see how condition $(ii)$ applies. For this example the dropoff of the tails is exponential. Is it possible to put $e^{-x}$ in the form $(ii)$ requires, $x^{-\alpha}L(x)$ for slowly varying $L$ and $\alpha<2$. Why is there a condition limiting how fast the tails drop off? That's the opposite of the usual CLT condition. But $(ii)$ must apply by the necessity direction and the CLT result.

Comment: The double exponential distribution does not meet assumption (ii) at all, does it? Hence the theorem does not apply to this distribution (and indeed, for the double exponential distribution, $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution, not $S_n/\log n$). In other words, (i) and (ii) are **hypotheses** here.

Comment: @Did how do you interpret his remark "the conditions are necessary for the existence of $a_n,b_n$"? Given that the double exponential satisfies the conclusion of the theorem with $a_n=\sqrt{n},b_n=0$, shouldn't (i) and (ii) follow by necessity? Do you understand him to be referring to something other than (i),(ii) when he says "the conditions"?

Comment: The meaning is not very clear but once again, the double exponential distribution satisfies neither the hypotheses (i) and (ii) nor the conclusion of Theorem 3.7.2.